# Can GCC/GNU ld be made to demangle names of a new language?

Tags: c, gcc, ld

I have designed my own programming language and I am in the process of developing a compiler for it. The language gets transted to plain C, then `gcc` is invoked to compile as well as link programs made in this language, called Perun.

Name mangling is involved, similar to how it's done in C++. I have a utility named `perun-demangle` which can convert mangled name into a human-readable form. Example:

```
$ perun-demangle Per_FD3std4priv5posix14FDOutputStream10writeBytes_M3std4priv5posix14FDOutputStream_0_AU8
std.priv.posix.FDOutputStream.writeBytes(std.priv.posix.FDOutputStream, byte_t[])
```

If we try to link a program but the definition of that function is missing, then `gcc` (invoked by the Perun compiler to link the program) simply outputs:

```
undefined reference to `Per_FD3std4priv5posix14FDOutputStream10writeBytes_M3std4priv5posix14FDOutputStream_0_AU8'
```

However, when linking C++ code using `g++`, the linker understands how to demangle the C++ symbols and outputs their human-readable form in the error messages. Presumably, it does this using `c++filt`.

My question is: can I somehow make the linker use `perun-demangle` instead of `c++filt` to demangle the symbols in error messages automatically?

Comment: Did you read all of the documentation? And since GCC and binutils are open source you could additionally look through the sources of the linker(s). It should be not too difficult to find the place where demangling is done. If there is a call to `c++filt` it should be easily be found for example by grep.

Comment: @thebusybee or even just temporarily move the c++filt binary and replace it with his own.

Comment: @fugiefire Well, yes, I used to do those hacks, too. But I tend to forget and weeks later I was wondering why things don't work. ;-) For a quick test it is OK.

Comment: @thebusybee how about writing a bash script that does it for you? :)

Comment: @fugiefire There might be a supported way to call another demangling filter, and at best it is documented. Why should I use a possibly fragile hack if some research leads to a stable solution? This is what the OP is looking for, as I understand.

Comment: @thebusybee true, I’m just throwing ideas :)

Comment: @fugiefire And I caught it! :-D Have a nice day.